# Difference member initialisation between C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, class

Consider the following code snippets:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {cout << "First creation";}
    A(int x) {cout << "Second creation";}
};

class B {
    A first;
public:
    B() {first = A(2);}
};
```

When creating a new B object, First and second creation get printed (to avoid this one uses member initialisation lists). However, I can't reproduce this behaviour in java (It only prints "Second creation"):

```
class A {
    public A() {System.out.println("First creation");}
    public A(int x) {System.out.println("Second creation");}
}

class B {
    A first;
    public B() {first = new A(3);}
}
```

This indicates that there is some difference how Java and C++ treat those objects, and since I'm a C++ beginner, it would be interesting to understand why this is the case.

Comment: Java and C++ are totally different languages. You should not (and largely cannot) use one to reason about the other.

Comment: In your C code, this `A first;` already creates an instance; that is the "First creation".

Comment: In the C++ code, `B() {first = A(2);}` should be `B() : first{2} { }`.

Comment: If you wanted to call both CTORs (CTOR chaining) in Java, you'd have to re-write `public A(int x) {System.out.println("Second creation");}` to `public A(int x) {this(); System.out.println("Second creation");}`

Comment: And writing `A first; public B() {first = new A(3);}` will mess something up. Either compiler error, or pointers break. Because `new A(3);` returns an A* (pointer), not a stack instance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch wow, I didn't know that, always thought they were the same

Comment: Diamond inheritance, operator overloading, template types, rtti, byte-code vs native-code and automatic garbage collection, just listing some differences off the top of my head.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, I know that they are very different. That's why the intend of my question was to understand how they differ in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the member initializer goes before the method, AND the object A as a member is an actual object, so you have

1. B() -> B.first - A() default ctor() initialization
2. B() -> B() method.  Has A.first=(temporary A(2) parameter ctor initialization).

In C++ if you declared a private assignment operator the code would then not compile.

In Java, however, the A is a pointer to some object of type A.  By default it is initialized with null (pointing to nothing) and once your B() ctor is called you then create a new object to initialize it with.  Only one A involved.